# Weird GORM behaviour in grails when refreshing the page (F5)

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

i have an entity (Author) and a controller action that renders all the authors.

```
def index = {
    def list = Author.list()
    render(view: 'index', model: ['allauthors' : list])
}
```

When rendering the page, a single query is executed as expected :

```
Hibernate: 
  select
    this_.id as id0_0_,
    this_.version as version0_0_,
    this_.name as name0_0_
  from
    author this_
```

However, when i press Refresh (F5) then a select statement is executed for each author (here i have 3 authors) :

```
Hibernate: 
select
    author0_.id as id0_0_,
    author0_.version as version0_0_,
    author0_.name as name0_0_
from
    author author0_ 
where
    author0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
select
    author0_.id as id0_0_,
    author0_.version as version0_0_,
    author0_.name as name0_0_
from
    author author0_ 
where
    author0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
select
    author0_.id as id0_0_,
    author0_.version as version0_0_,
    author0_.name as name0_0_
from
    author author0_ 
where
    author0_.id=?
```

Why this happends???

Comment: It could be because your second level caching is turned off by default. If you forsee the refresh functionality happening a lot, you can cache the list query by passing the cache parameter in the list() call.

Comment: the odd thing is why the statement: Author.book() execute the normal single select statement for the first time, but when refreshing it executes multiple select statements for each author! Any ideas?

Comment: I added the hibernate tag because I feel that this could be better explained at the hibernate level and not the Grails level.

Comment: I have just tested this with grails 1.3.7 and default DataSources, scaffolded controller and views - and only one select statement is made with each call to index action, no matter how many times I refresh.

What version of grails? What does you DataSources and Author look like?

Comment: I propose that you added some "logging statement" before and after def list = Author.list() There maybe another statement that trigger the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this has to do with the query cache.  If you have

```
cache.use_query_cache = true
```

in your Datasource.groovy but do NOT have cacheing set up in your domain class the cache appears to be evicting all of the entries on each `list()` and having to re-cache each one (just a guess).

If you add cacheing to your domain the multiple selects go away - in fact NO selects are done when I refresh after adding this:

```
static mapping = {
    cache true
}
```